# Batch Remote Copy

Tags: file, batch-file, xcopy

I am interested in creating a batch file (ran on my computer) that can copy files from a server location to a computer connected to my network.

Something like:

```
xcopy //SERVER/FILE CONNECTEDCOMPUTER
```

It would be fine if I had to run the batch from the server or something like that. I just want to be able to remotely send a file to a connected computer.

Comment: Why don't you just share a folder so you and the remote computer and the server can all see the file?

Comment: I need to send the file directly to the other computer.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have access to the files (the files are on a share you can read from), XCOPY should work fine. If you map a share to a local drive letter, you have the normal syntax for XCOPY as if you copy locally.
Without a mapped drive, simply use something like this to copy from server to C:\ :
XCOPY \SERVERNAME\SHARENAME\FILEORDIRECTORIES C:\

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I was just hoping that there was a way to do it without sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your aversion for sharing if what you want to do is share files... but you could install an `ssh` server for Windows on the remote machine, such as this - [Bitvise](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd)

Then all you need to do is use

```
winscp file remote:
```

or

```
pscp file remote:
```

if you go the `putty` route.

Or you could install the free Filezilla FTP Server on the remote machine and send your file via FTP.